# How to capture stdout/stderr in setup_class?

Tags: python, pytest

Inside `pytest` tests, you can capture the streams using the `capfd` and `capsys` fixtures. But this doesn't work in `setup_class`.

Is there another way to do this?

What I would like to do is something like:

```
class TestSomething:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls, capsys):
        do_work_and_print_stuff()
        cls.outerr = capsys.readouterr()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `-r` switch when running tests?

Comment: Doesn't seem related: `The -r flag can be used to display a “short test summary info” at the end of the test session, making it easy in large test suites to get a clear picture of all failures, skips, xfails, etc.`

Comment: can you add an example to your question? Also, I believe the pytest method is `setUpClass()` and not `setup_class()`

Comment: Thanks, added a code example for clarity. `setUpClass()` is for `unittest`, not `pytest`.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to use a wrapper class for `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`:

```
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, base_stream):
        self.base_stream = base_stream
        self.content = ''

    def write(self, message):
        self.base_stream.write(message)
        self.content += message

    def flush(self):
        self.base_stream.flush()


class TestSomething:
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        sys.stdout = Logger(sys.stdout)
        sys.stderr = Logger(sys.stderr)

        do_work_and_print_stuff()  # Do your thing

        cls.out = sys.stdout.content
        cls.err = sys.stderr.content
        sys.stdout = sys.stdout.base_stream
        sys.stderr = sys.stderr.base_stream
```

But it would be nice to do this using some `pytest` built in functionality such as the `capsys` and `capfd` fixtures.